# Use spring reactive webclient to pass protobuff request

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers

I am using spring framework reactive webclient to make a call like below

```
webClient.post()
    .uri("/v/score/$model")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .bodyValue(gson.toJson(request))
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header("Client-Id", clientId)
    .awaitExchange()
    .awaitBody<ScoringResponse>()
```

which is working fine. Now I wan to pass the request as a protobuff object instead of json. How can I do that ?

Comment: Your code excerpt seemed to be lacking for a double quote (in the `uri` call) that I tried to fix. Could you check it?

Comment: It's working fine for json, I want to know how to make it work for protobuff.

Comment: you don't answer to my comment. What you posted could not compile

Comment: sorry maybe a typo while copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Set the media type to `application/octet-stream` and pass your proto model in a byte array form by using the `.toByteArray()` method. On the receiving end you can use the **static** method `{proto generated class}.parseFrom({your bytes come here})` to rebuild the proto object.

Do not forget the POST method request is basically a body content ;)